# Send Location of User in Background Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, core-location

I am building an app where the user clicks a button and for 60mins (or any amount of time) we keep track of them by uploading their location to a server. Currently we are using 'Did Update Locations' function to send the users location to firebase in real-time.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

}
```

This system works but it spams the server sending the location of the user to the server once every second.

This is too much data and we would only need to send the users location to the server once every 10-30 seconds.

What can we do send the users location once every 10-30 seconds?

Comment: Why don't you just compare timestamps of current and previous location and upload location only if time difference is more than 30 sec?

Comment: @Shmidt you should add an answer

Comment: @Paulw11 OK, I'll add answer in 5 min

Comment: @Paulw11 Please see my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private var locman = CLLocationManager()
    private var startTime: Date? //An instance variable, will be used as a previous location time.

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    guard let loc = locations.last else { return }

    let time = loc.timestamp

    guard var startTime = startTime else {
        self.startTime = time // Saving time of first location, so we could use it to compare later with second location time.
        return //Returning from this function, as at this moment we don't have second location. 
    }

    let elapsed = time.timeIntervalSince(startTime) // Calculating time interval between first and second (previously saved) locations timestamps.

    if elapsed > 30 { //If time interval is more than 30 seconds
        print("Upload updated location to server")
        updateUser(location: loc) //user function which uploads user location or coordinate to server.

        startTime = time //Changing our timestamp of previous location to timestamp of location we already uploaded.

    }
}
```

Comment: I would add some commentary that briefly explains what you are doing (although the code is fairly clear).

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for noting that. Will do.

Comment: Will this code still execute when the app is moved to background?

Comment: Hi @kinza i am trying to send the location coordinate to server when app is in background. do you find any solution for the same?

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var backgroundUpdateTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier!
var bgtimer = Timer()
var latitude: Double = 0.0
var longitude: Double = 0.0
var current_time = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
var timer = Timer()
var f = 0
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.doBackgroundTask()
    return true
}


func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("Entering foreBackground")
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("Entering Background")
   // self.doBackgroundTask()
}

func doBackgroundTask() {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.beginBackgroundUpdateTask()

        self.StartupdateLocation()


        self.bgtimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:-1, target: self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.bgtimer(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.current.add(self.bgtimer, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
        RunLoop.current.run()

        self.endBackgroundUpdateTask()

    }
}

func beginBackgroundUpdateTask() {
    self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
        self.endBackgroundUpdateTask()
    })
}

func endBackgroundUpdateTask() {
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundUpdateTask)
    self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}

func StartupdateLocation() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Error while requesting new coordinates")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

    self.latitude = locValue.latitude
    self.longitude = locValue.longitude
    f+=1
    print("New Coordinates: \(f) ")
    print(self.latitude)
    print(self.longitude)
}

@objc func bgtimer(_ timer:Timer!){
    sleep(2)
  /*  if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
         timer.invalidate()
    }*/
    self.updateLocation()
}

func updateLocation() {
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}}
```

I added the sleep function to delay of calling the location and send the information to server

Since this is running in both the app is active and goes to background. If you want only background process, remove or comment the function self.doBackgroundTask() from  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and remove the comment for self.doBackgroundTask() in the applicationdidEnterBackground. And then remove the comment in the function bgtimer(), since the background process has to stop once the app comes to active state.

Comment: Note, that background task will work only a couple of minutes then it stops.

Answer (score 1):

Apps normally get suspended (no longer get CPU time) a moment after being moved to the background. You can ask for extra background time, but the system only gives you 3 minutes.

Only a very limited class of apps are allowed to run in the background for longer than that. Mapping/GPS applications are one of those categories. However, your app is not a mapping/GPS application, so I doubt if Apple would approve it.

Bottom line: I think you might be out of luck running your location queries for more than 3 minutes.

### EDIT:

As Paulw11 points out, you can use the significant location change service to get location updates when the device moves by large distances.

Comment: I would disagree. You can certainly get a non-mapping app approved with "always" location permissions. You need to have a valid reason for location, comply with the privacy requirements and put a disclaimer about potential impact on battery life in your app store description.  The issue here isn't the ability to get updates in the background, but rather the frequency of updates.  Unfortunately the only solution to that is to "throw away" updates if they arrive faster than you want to report them even though this wastes battery,

Comment: "Always" location permission is different then always running in the background. Unless you have permission to run constantly in the background, you have to use something like significant  location change notifications or location region "geofences". Those things will wake up your app (or re-launch it if needed) and give it notifications, but not constant high-resolution location updates. Requesting location updates from the location manager only works if you are running in the foreground or have been given permission to actively run in the background.

Comment: Apple only allows apps to actively run in the background under very limited circumstances, and usually for very limited time periods.

Comment: True, but location services is one of those limited circumstances, so the OP is ok on that case.  iOS will launch your app into the background (for a limited time) from the suspended state when a location update is delivered. This can continue indefinitely as each update takes only a second or so.

Comment: It is.  I have apps in the app store that use long term location updates from the suspended state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140019/discussion-between-paulw11-and-duncan-c).